# How to mock a function which is without class?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I want to mock a free function which is not a class member.

It is declared in `.h` with its definition in `.cpp`.

How do I mock this function?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "mock a function"?

Comment: I mean I want to make an expect call to this function so that when it comes for execution it should return the expected value, so how to make an expect call for a function if it is not member of any class?? @besworland

Comment: @besworland : it's a term which is fairly specific to Google Mock. It means replacing the function by a scripted implementation. You do so when you want to test another function which uses the mocked function. To validate that the tested function works correctly, you generally need to test that it can accept all error codes etc. A scripted implementation can more easily generate all error codes.

Comment: @MSalters Thank you, will read later on about it!

Answer (score 3):

Create the mock function definition and don't link the original .cpp file.

This is known as a [Link Seam](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=3) as described by Michael Feathers in [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052).

Comment: The chapter about this(Testing Effectively With Legacy Code) from Michael Feathers' Working Effectively With Legacy Code book is available online here for free: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417 .

Comment: This technique is also described in the Modern C++ Programming with Test-Driven Development: Code Better, Sleep Bett book by Jeff Langr: https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Programming-Test-Driven-Development-Better/dp/1937785483

Comment: Thanks, @KulaGGin, for the links. Can't believe this is still relevant over 17 years later.